# Rendering variable in Ruby on Rails not correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rendering

I am trying to render something from my controller action.

```
def show

@bookmark = Bookmark.all
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @bookmark }
end
end
```

This above is the action in the controller.

The html erb file for show is :

```
<p>
<b>Url:</b>
<%= @bookmark.each do |book| %>
<li><%= book.url%>
<b>Title:</b>
<li><%= book.title%>
<% end %>
</p>
```

I am getting output too, but additional to that I am getting extra things. The output is :

```
Url:

www.google.com Title:
h
www.gmail.com Title:
hiw
asd Title:
as
sd Title:
ad
asd Title:
as
asd Title:
as
asfa Title:
ada
www.mrabhiram.github.com Title:
abhi
www.mrabhiram.github.com Title:
abhi 
www.mrabhiram.github.com Title:
abhi 


[#<Bookmark id: 1, title: "h", url: "www.google.com", tags: "php,python", created_at:    "2012-12-12 06:02:21", updated_at: "2012-12-12 06:02:21">, #<Bookmark id: 2, title: "hiw", url: "www.gmail.com", tags: "mail", created_at: "2012-12-12 06:02:41", updated_at: "2012-12-12 06:02:41">, #<Bookmark id: 3, title: "as", url: "asd", tags: "asd", created_at: "2012-12-12 06:07:41", updated_at: "2012-12-12 06:07:41">, #<Bookmark id: 4, title: "ad", url: "sd", tags: "dsfsd", created_at: "2012-12-12 06:11:04", updated_at: "2012-12-12 06:11:04">, #<Bookmark id: 5, title: "as", url: "asd", tags: "asd", created_at: "2012-12-12 06:22:36", updated_at: "2012-12-12 06:22:36">, #<Bookmark id: 6, title: "as", url: "asd", tags: "asda", created_at: "2012-12-12 06:25:33", updated_at: "2012-12-12 06:25:33">, #<Bookmark id: 7, title: "ada", url: "asfa", tags: "fa", created_at: "2012-12-12 07:41:16", updated_at: "2012-12-12 07:41:16">, #<Bookmark id: 8, title: "abhi", url: "www.mrabhiram.github.com", tags: "abhiram,php", created_at: "2012-12-12 07:45:29", updated_at: "2012-12-12 07:45:29">, #<Bookmark id: 9, title: "abhi", url: "www.mrabhiram.github.com", tags: "abhiram,php", created_at: "2012-12-12 07:46:19", updated_at: "2012-12-12 07:46:19">, #<Bookmark id: 10, title: "abhi", url: "www.mrabhiram.github.com", tags: "abhiram,php", created_at: "2012-12-12 07:48:28", updated_at: "2012-12-12 07:48:28">]
```

I should get rid of the array printing at last. I only want the records to be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<% ... %>` instead of `<%= ... %>`:

```
<% @bookmark.each do |book| %>
```

See: [eRB <%=](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/81219)

**Update (in response to comments):**

To avoid an error if there is only one bookmark, wrap the instance variable in `Array()`:

```
<% Array(@bookmark).each do |book| %>
```

Incidentally I would suggest renaming your instance variable from `@bookmark` to `@bookmarks`.

Comment: Thanks dat solved my problem. I got another problem. The code <% @bookmark.each do |book| %> works only for multiple rows. If i had single row, it would show error like undefined method `each' for #<Bookmark:0x3e2e3f0>  . What should i do to print single row also.

Comment: Updated my answer, but really you should have posted this as a new question.

Comment: p.s. if this is the correct answer to your question, please accept it. Thanks!